# Mongoose + TypeScript : ObjectId constructor "Expected 0 arguments, but got 1" ... and it works

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I have an error "Expected 0 arguments, but got 1" on this line (idProduct is a string) :

|`new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(idProduct)`

But that's only underlined and the code works correctly....

My code is :

```
async function test(idProduct: string) {
    const test = await screenModel.aggregate([
        { '$match': { 'productId': new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(idProduct)} },
    ]);
}
```

If I open the index.d.ts in mongoose/types, all `mongodb.ObjectId` are underlined with the error "Namespace '"[.....]/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb.ts34"' has no exported member 'ObjectId'"

I am with mongoose 6.2.9

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you very much
C.

Comment: I think you may be using the wrong `ObjectId` there, see [this page in the documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#objectids).

Comment: Can you post your function code?

Comment: If I use `mongoose.ObjectId` I have an error : `Property 'ObjectId' does not exist on type 'typeof import("mongoose")'`

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue and this worked for me.
Instead of using `ObjectId` from `mongoose` I imported it from `bson`

```
import { ObjectId } from 'bson'

async function test(idProduct: string) {
    const test = await screenModel.aggregate([
        { '$match': { 'productId': new ObjectId(idProduct)} },
    ]);
}
```

I hope this solves the issue.